# Firestore Security: Deny Update / Write If Field In Request Resource (Works in simulator, not IRL)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have user profile data stored in Firestore. I also have some profile fields in Firestore that dictate user permission levels. I want to deny the user the ability to write or update to their Firestore profile if they include any changes that would impact their permission level.

**Example fields in user's firestore doc for their profile**

```
permissionLevel: 1
favoriteColor: red
```

Document ID is the same as the user's authentication uid (because only the user should be able to read / write / update their profile).

I want to deny updates or writes if the user's firestore update or write includes a permissionLevel field, to prevent the user from changing their own permission level.

**Current Firestore Rules**

This is working fine when I build an object in the simulator to test including or not including a field called "permissionLevel". But this is denying all update / write requests from my client-side web SDK.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Deny all access by default
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // Allow users to read, write, and update their own profiles only
    match /users/{userId} {
        // Allow users to read their own profile
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      // Allow users to write / update their own profile as long as no "permissionLevel" field is trying to be added or updated
      allow write, update: if request.auth.uid == userId &&
            request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["permissionLevel"]) == false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Client-Side Function**

For example, this function attempts to just update when the user was last active by updating a firestore field. This returns the error `Error updating user refresh time:  Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

```
/**
 * Update User Last Active
 * Updates the user's firestore profile with their "last active" time
 * @param {object} user is the user object from the login auth state
 * @returns {*} dispatched action
 */
export const updateLastActive = (user) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firestore().settings({/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true});

        // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
        var db = firestore();

        // Get the user's ID from the user retrieved user object
        var uid = firebaseAuth().currentUser["uid"];

        // Get last activity time (last time token issued to user)
        user.getIdTokenResult()
        .then(res => {
            let lastActive = res["issuedAtTime"];

            // Get reference to this user's profile in firestore
            var userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);

            // Make the firestore update of the user's profile
            console.log("Firestore write (updating last active)");
            return userRef.update({
                "lastActive": lastActive
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
            // console.log("User lastActive time successfully updated.");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error updating user refresh time: ", err);
        })
    }
}
```

This same function works fine if I remove this line from the firestore rules. I don't see how they have anything to do with each other, and why it would work fine in the simulator.
`request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["permissionLevel"]) == false;`

Answer (score 4):

### Update

I got a notice that `writeFields` is deprecated. I have another [another answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995625/8177355) which uses `request.resource.data` which may be an alternative that is useful to people who arrive here.

---

### Original Answer

OK, I found a solution, but I can't find any official documentation in the firebase docs to support this. It doesn't work in the simulation, but it works IRL.

**Replace** (from my example above)

`request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["permissionLevel"]) == false`

**With This**

`!("permissionLevel" in request.writeFields);`

**Full Working Permissions Example**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    // Deny all access by default
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    
    // Allow users to read, write, and update their own profiles only
    match /users/{userId} {
        // Allow users to read their own profile
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      
      // Allow users to write / update their own profile as long as no "admin" field is trying to be added or created
      allow write, update: if request.auth.uid == userId &&
            !("permissionLevel" in request.writeFields);
    }
  }
}
```

This successfully prevents an update or write whenever the key `permissionLevel` exists in the firestore request map object, and allows other updates as intended.

**Documentation Help**

[Firestore Security Docs Index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/index-all) lists "rules.firestore.Request#writeFields" - but when you click it, the resulting page doesn't even mention "writeFields" at all.

I used the principles based on [rules.Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) for

**k in x**  Check if key k exists in map x

Comment: Just a heads -up, `writeFields` is deprecated without any replacement, you have to use workarounds...

Comment: Thanks, just updated to suggest `request.resource.data` as a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two other things you could consider doing for adding permission levels:

1. Create a separate subcollection for the user that will then contain a document with information you do not want the user to be able to change. That document can be given different permission controls.
2. **Use Firebase Auth Tokens with Custom Claims**. Bonus: this method will not trigger reads on the database. I recommend checking out these Firecasts:

   - [Controlling Data Access Using Firebase Auth Custom Claims](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs)
   - [Minting Custom Tokens with the Admin SDK for Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi2dv6NcHWA)

[Add the Firebase Admin SDK to Your Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) guide is also very helpful.

I am new to the development game, but this what I use to manually create custom claims using ItelliJ IDEA:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserRecord;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class App {

    //This will be the UID of the user we modify
    private static final String UID = "[uid of the user you want to modify]"; 

    //Different Roles
    private static final int USER_ROLE_VALUE_BASIC = 0; //Lowest Level - new user
    private static final int USER_ROLE_VALUE_COMMENTER = 1; 
    private static final int USER_ROLE_VALUE_EDITOR = 2; 
    private static final int USER_ROLE_VALUE_MODERATOR = 3; 
    private static final int USER_ROLE_VALUE_SUPERIOR = 4; 
    private static final int USER_ROLE_VALUE_ADMIN = 9;

    private static final String FIELD_ROLE = "role";

    //Used to Toggle Different Tasks - Currently only one task
    private static final boolean SET_PRIVILEGES = true; //true to set User Role

    //The privilege level being assigned to the uid.
    private static final int SET_PRIVILEGES_USER_ROLE = USER_ROLE_VALUE_BASIC;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setting this up
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("./ServiceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://[YOUR_DATABASE_NAME].firebaseio.com")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        // Set privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
        if (SET_PRIVILEGES){
            Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
            claims.put(FIELD_ROLE, SET_PRIVILEGES_USER_ROLE);
            try{
                // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
                // next time a new one is issued.
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(UID, claims);

                // Lookup the user associated with the specified uid.
                UserRecord user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(
                System.out.println(user.getCustomClaims().get(FIELD_ROLE));

            }catch (FirebaseAuthException e){
                System.out.println("FirebaseAuthException caught: " + e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The build.gradle dependency is currently:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0'
```