# Firebase/Firestore - How do I create a new document for a new user

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When using Google SignIn I want Firestore to create a users/document for the new user matching the user.uid I have. I used the Firestore rules from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995625/12029941).

Edit: However, still get this error:

```
C:\Users\alobre\Documents\Programmieren\BountyHunter\node_modules\react-devtools-core\dist\backend.js:32 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
    at FirestoreCollectionReference.get (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:133094:39)
    at _callee$ (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:197066:93)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24879:19)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25052:24)
    at Generator.next (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24922:23)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24879:19)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24952:22)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24982:13
    at tryCallTwo (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26948:7)
```

Here is my code:
addUser

```
export default function addUser(user){
  console.log(firestore())
  firestore()
   .collection('users')
   .doc(user.uid)
   .set({
     user
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('User added!');
   }); 
 }
```

---

called when pressing login button

```
async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
  GoogleSignin.signIn()
  .then((data) => {
    const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken);
    return auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
  })
  .then((user) => {
    addUser(user)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const { code, message } = error;
  });
}
```

My Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
// Allow users to create a document for themselves in the users collection
    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.resource.id == request.auth.uid &&
        !("admin" in request.resource.data);
    }
    
    // Allow users to read, write, update documents that have the same ID as their user id
    match /users/{userId} {   
        // Allow users to read their own profile (doc id same as user id)
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      
      // Allow users to write / update their own profile as long as no "admin"
      // field is trying to be added or created - unless they are already an admin
      allow write, update: if request.auth.uid == userId &&
        (
          !("admin" in request.resource.data) ||
          get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true // allow admin to update their own profile
        )
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to explain what isn't working the way you expect.  I'm noticing that you're not checking for errors on the call to `set()` the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:
the firestore rules are correct. However i got a error that the permission is denied.
the reason:

```
match /users/{document=**} {
  allow create: if request.resource.id == request.auth.uid &&
    !("admin" in request.resource.data);
}
```

the request.resource.id does not match the request auth.uid
I was trying to create a document with the uid of the GoogleSignin module (which doesn't even have a uid but a id).

The correct way would be:

```
.then(
  Post(auth().currentUser)
)
```

Firestore needs this auth().currentUser.uid and I was giving the GoogleSignin.signIn().uid which does not match the request.auth.uid