# Firestore allow creation of doc if docId matches uid of user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I see that there are answers for this question from 2019:
[Allow User To Create Doc Only If New Doc ID is same as User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993123/firestore-security-rules-allow-user-to-create-doc-only-if-new-doc-id-is-same-as)
and they don't work for me

I want to restrict the creation of a doc in the userAccounts collection only to those who are authenticated and the docId needs to match the uid of the logged in user.

here are three versions of rules I have tried that do not work:

```js
    match /userAccounts/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.id;
      allow create: if path("/databases/$(database)/documents/userAccounts/" + request.auth.uid) == request.path;
    }
```

i also tried

```js
    match /userAccounts/{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.id;
      allow create: if path("/databases/$(database)/documents/userAccounts/" + request.auth.uid) == request.path;
    }
```

I tried the rules one at a time and no combination works for my scenario.  Has the rules engine changed since 2019 so that this is not possible?

### EDIT 1:

here is my current rules:

```js
    match /userAccounts/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, update: if if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

Here is the jest unit test that is testing against the rules in a local emulator:

```js
 currentUser = testEnv.authenticatedContext('testUserId123');

  it('only current user can CREATE userAccount for current user', async () => {
    const createByUser = currentUser
      .firestore()
      .collection('userAccounts')
      .add({ userId: 'testUserId123', displayName: 'test name' });

    await assertSucceeds(createByUser);
  });
```

How can I make a rule that only allows the current user to create a doc with an id that matches the auth.uid?

Comment: Please edit the question to show enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  This includes 1) your rules 2) any relevant document data, 3) your app code that should trigger the rule.  And no, nothing has significantly changed.  You're probably just doing something wrong.

Comment: This use-case is quite well documented in [owner-only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access). If that doesn't work for you, we don't need to see every variation you tried, but just the one thing you thought should work, but that didn't. For those rules, we'll want to see the minimal rules and **the code that doesn't work**. And in that code, prove that it meets the requirement of the one rule you shared (i.e. have an `if` that checks the same thing that the rules check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

It turns out that I had a **spelling mistake** in my unit tests.  I had some places where I used **userAccount/** instead of **userAccounts/** missing the plural.  Once I got that sorted the following rules give me exactly what I need:

```js
    match /userAccounts/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, update: if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

SMH